# How do I get a boolean array from an array A with multiple conditions in python?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
A = np.arange(0,20,1)
A<7
```

The above code will return a boolean array where its elements are true when A<7 and otherwise false. 
How do I get such a boolean array for x < A < 7?

Comment: Try `(A<7) & (A>3)` (for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your x = 3, then:

```
a = np.arange(0,20,1)
a
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19])

(a>3) & (a<7)
array([False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False])
```

If you want an or condition you can replace `&` with `|`:

```
(a<3) | (a>7) #Less than 3 or greater than 7
array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True])
```

Answer (score 2):

Choose x value and then :

```
x = 3
np.logical_and(x<A, A<7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a list comprehension:

```
x = 3
bools = [i<7 and i> x for i in A]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import timeit

A = np.arange(0, 20, 1)
# print(A)
x = 3


def fun():
    return [x < i < 7 for i in A]


def fun2():
    return (A < 7) & (A > 3)


def fun3():
    return np.logical_and(x < A, A < 7)

def fun4():
    return [i < 7 and i > x for i in A]


print('fun()', timeit.timeit('fun()', number=10000, globals=globals()))
print('fun2()', timeit.timeit('fun2()', number=10000, globals=globals()))
print('fun3()', timeit.timeit('fun3()', number=10000, globals=globals()))
print('fun4()', timeit.timeit('fun4()', number=10000, globals=globals()))
```

**output:**

execution time(in seconds):

```
fun() 0.055701432000205386
fun2() 0.016561345997615717
fun3() 0.016588653001235798
fun4() 0.0446821750010713
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `numpy.logical_and` for that task, example:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(0,20,1)
B = np.logical_and(3<A,A<7)
print(B)
```

Output:

```
[False False False False  True  True  True False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False]
```